# Need to accurately sort a text file into subcategories

Tags: python, sorting

EDIT:

The code accurately pulls up the routing table and can ask for specific routes but, I still can't figure out how to sort the routing table into specific groups. When I sort it creates new text files but the contents are wrong. In each file created it simply fills the text file with the last line of the routing table. This is my current code:

```py
import subprocess
import os
# Open the routing table and keep the same format
def Call_Routing_Table():
    out = subprocess.Popen("route", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = out.stdout.read().decode('ascii')
    return out.splitlines()

#Sort the Contents of the table into their respective CIDR blocks
def SortCIDRBlocks(text):

    word = "128.0.0.0"
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
             CIDR1 = open("CIDR1.txt","w+")
             CIDR1.write(line)
             line + 1
            
    word = "192.0.0.0"
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            CIDR2 = open("CIDR2.txt","w+")
            CIDR2.write(line)
            
    word = "224.0.0.0"
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            CIDR3 = open("CIDR3.txt","w+")
            CIDR3.write(line)
            
    word = "240.0.0.0"
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            CIDR4 = open("CIDR4.txt","w+")
            CIDR4.write(line)
    
    word = "255.255.255.0"
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            CIDR24 = open("CIDR24.txt","w+")
            CIDR24.write(line)

def Pull_Specific_Route(text):
    word = input('Enter desired route:')
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            print(line)

## Set the routing table to variable lines
lines = Call_Routing_Table()

## Call function to sort routing table into CIDR Blocks
SortCIDRBlocks(lines)

Pull_Specific_Route(lines)
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code as a snippet, not as an image

Comment: `out.stdout.read()` returns a single string.  It is pointless to "compose" anything.  `input` also returns a string.  It is pointless to pass its output to `str()`, and it is pointless to turn it into a list of one entry.

Comment: Why save the results to a file?  Just return a string (or list of strings) and pass that to your second function.

Comment: And what are you providing here is that not more easily done as `route | grep /27`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This removes much of your unnecessary processing, but as I said, this is just duplicating the easier to type command `route | grep /27`:

```
import subprocess

def Call_Routing_Table():
    out = subprocess.Popen("route print", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = out.stdout.read().decode('ascii')
    return out.splitlines()

def Pull_Specific_Route(text):
    word = input('Enter desired route:')
    for line in text:
        if word in line:
            print(line)

lines = Call_Routing_Table()
Pull_Specific_Route(lines)
```